# Titlepage and Section 1 on first page? Not sure what I've done (Custom \titlepage)

Tags: titles

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
```

and then I've just used

```
\begin{titlepage}
 my stuff 
\end{titlepage}
```

and put in my own custom stuff, then I do

```
\section{}
```

The problem is that the section starts on a new page. I can't find any way to put it on the same page as the title.

Comment: A titlepage is a whole page.

Comment: Perhaps see how to obtain the first section on the same page as a custom  title with the `titling` package.

Comment: One important thing to mention is: There is absolutely no need to use the `titlepage` environment. It is one of the most misunderstood and unneeded environments available (IMHO).

Answer (score 3):

The standard `article` class can automatically produce titles in two ways :

1. Title at the top of the first page that also contains Section 1. This is the defaults behavior
2. Title alone on the first page, the normal text starting on page 2. This mode is defined by the option `titlepage` in `documentclass[a4paper,titlepage]{article}`

In both cases, the title will be produced by the command `\maketitle`.

On the opposite, the `titlepage` environnment can be used to produce a custom title, with more information than the title_author_date used by standard title (like logo, supervisor and so one) or fancy formatting. The only thing it does is suppressing the head and foot (ie `\thispagestyle{empty}`) and adding a `\newpage` on exit.

**Edit**

Hence, if you want to issue a custom title but keep the section on the same page, dont use `titlepage`, but prefer another environment like `\begin{center}...\end{center}`, or `\begin{minipage}{somewidth}...\end{minipage}`, or a `tabular`, or any combination of them depending on the layout you want to obtain, and adding the content and formatting inside this environment. 
And in such case do not use  neither the `titlepage` option nor the `\maketitle` command.

And you can add a 
`\thispagestyle{empty}`, 
outside the outermost environment if you want to mimick what `titlepage` would have done for the header and footer.

Comment: I have slightly improved my answer by suggesting a method to produce a custom title that does not use the whole page.